# Select columns by (iloc) name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to get the contents of a dataframe to filter by name

```
X = df.iloc[108:, 1:48]

y = df.iloc[108:, -1]

#108 to just shy of last

#training
tx = X.iloc[0:int(split), 1:48]

df1 = df.iloc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']]
```

doesn't work

```
File "<ipython-input-77-c23d3211e2bf>", line 51 df1 = df.loc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']]df1 = df.loc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']] ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax –
```

yet

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, [1, 2]]
```

produces

```
    date    CPIAUCSL
0   1991-01-31  134.700
1   1991-02-28  134.800
2   1991-03-31  134.800
```

Comment: What is your question? What is `df`? What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: What's this meant to mean: `y = df.iloc[108:, -1]`? This certainly isn't `108 to just shy of last`. It means `108th row onwards, and final column`. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: that's exactly what I think it means.  108th row onward, final column

Comment: my question is how to search by column such as df1 = df.iloc[:, ['date', 2]] or df1 = df.iloc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to slice based on column number 1 (dates) and 2 (CPIAUCSL).

df.iloc slices only on column and row indexnumber, not on column names. To slice based on names, you should use df.loc. So in your last example:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']]
```

If you can provide more information about what exactly you want and what your data looks like, we could be able to help you a bit more.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-77-c23d3211e2bf>", line 51
    df1 = df.loc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']]df1 = df.loc[:, ['date', 'CPIAUCSL']]
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax